# SQL Statement is changing value it was not told to set

Tags: java, sql, timestamp

I've got a program to update wage information in a database over a certain period.  It looks like this:

```
Date prevDate = sdf.parse(prevStart);
Date curDate = sdf.parse(curStart);
Date nextDate = sdf.parse(nextStart);
String sql = "UPDATE schedules SET `rate`=?, `wage`=(hours * ?) WHERE (`e_name`=? AND `day`=?)";
while (prevDate.getTime() < curDate.getTime()) {
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setDouble(1, prevAmount);
    stmt.setDouble(2, prevAmount);
    stmt.setString(3, curEmployee);
    System.out.println("UpdatingPrevDate: " + new java.sql.Timestamp(prevDate.getTime()));
    stmt.setTimestamp(4, new java.sql.Timestamp(prevDate.getTime()));
    stmt.execute();
    prevDate.setTime(prevDate.getTime() + DAYLENGTH);
}
while (curDate.getTime() < nextDate.getTime()) { // change-over happens at correct point
    // Values seem correct
    System.out.println("UpdatingCurDate: " + new java.sql.Timestamp(curDate.getTime()));
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setDouble(1, curAmount);
    stmt.setDouble(2, curAmount);
    stmt.setString(3, curEmployee);
    stmt.setTimestamp(4, new java.sql.Timestamp(curDate.getTime()));
    stmt.execute(); // ------------- PROBLEM: This statement somehow sets the 'day' value to the current day
    curDate.setTime(curDate.getTime() + DAYLENGTH);
}
```

When I run it, the 'day' value for all entries handled by the second while-loop seems to get changed to the present day.  Since, I'm not telling the program to set that value, this doesn't make any sense to me.  What is going wrong?

FYI, the code for initializing the 'schedules' table looks like this:

```
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE schedules " +
                     "(id INTEGER not NULL, " +
                     " e_name VARCHAR(255), " + 
                     " day TIMESTAMP, " + // may change to VARCHAR with "2014/08/15" format
                     " start_time INTEGER(8), " + // 30 minute increments, 0 = 6:00 AM
                     " end_time INTEGER(8), " + 
                     " hours DOUBLE(8,1)," +
                     " rate DOUBLE(8,2)," +
                     " wage DOUBLE(8,2)," +
                     " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))"; 
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.execute();
```

Comment: Which SQL database specifically? In SQL Server, the (deprecated) `TIMESTAMP` is *automatically* updated when a row is touched.

Comment: I'm using MySQL Server 5.7.  Would you recommend changing the data type for the 'day' field, and if so, what should the declaration look like?